# How to best call a simple filter function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to improve the way I write javascript and am looking for a better way that calls a helper function and passes in a variable into that function rather than writing the actual filter function. To explain better, this works:

```
courses = courses.filter(course => course.id == 3);
```

But I'd rather just be able to put something like:

```
courses.filterId(3);
```

And put the helper function at the bottom.

So in other words, fixing the code inbetween the `/* ERROR INBETWEEN HERE */` comments may be the best way of asking for help.

Why is the error logging this message? `courses.filterId is not a function`

Thanks for any help here.

```js
let tutors = [
   {
     name: "Bob",
     age: 29,
      id: 1
   },
   {
     name: "Charlie",
     age: 24,
      id: 2
   },
   {
     name: "Elanor",
     age: 54,
      id: 3
   },
   {
     name: "Michael",
     age: 66,
      id: 4
   }
 ],
 courses = [
    {
      code: "AA01",
      description: "Javascript IIFEs, maps, filters, reduces, etc",
      id: 3
    },
    {
      code: "AO83",
      description: "Arrays, for of loops, etc",
      id: 1
    },
    {
      code: "AX40",
      description: "CSS, HTML",
      id: 3
    },
    {
      code: "BX92",
      description: "SQL, Node",
      id: 2
    },
    {
      code: "CC24",
      description: "PHP, Java",
      id: 1
    },
    {
      code: "DI30",
      description: "MongoDB",
      id: 4
    }
  ],
 theHTML = '<table><tr><th>Code</th><th>Description</th><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>',
 container = document.querySelector('#container');

 courses.forEach((course) =>
   tutors.forEach((tutor) =>
     tutor.id == course.id &&
     (course["name"] = tutor.name)
   )
 );

 /* USE THIS IF YOU WANNA FILTER */
 //courses = courses.filter(course => course.id == 3);

/* ERROR INBETWEEN HERE */
 function filterId(getID){
        return courses.filter(course => course.id == getID);
}
courses.filterId(3);
/* ERROR INBETWEEN HERE */

 courses.forEach(function(course) {
  theHTML += '<tr>';
  for (let column in course) {
   theHTML += '<td>' + course[column] + '</td>';
  }
  theHTML += '</tr>';
 });

 theHTML += ('</table>');

 container.innerHTML = theHTML;

 // without arrow functions
 /*
 courses.forEach(function(course) {
   tutors.forEach(function(tutor) {
     if (tutor.id == course.id) {
       course["name"] = tutor.name;
     }
   });
 });
 */
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```

Codepen URL: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GbMYJW

Comment: Your `courses` object doesn't have a function `filterId`. You've defined `filterId` as an independent function. So try calling it simply with `filterId(3)` (and not `courses.filterId(3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the function reference so that `courses.filterId` *is* a function.

`courses.filterId = filterId`

Then, use it like so:

`courses.filterId(3).forEach(...)`

Alternatively, you can define the function directly on the `courses.filterId` property:

```
courses.filterId = id => courses.filter(course => course.id === id)
```

```js
let tutors = [
    {
      name: "Bob",
      age: 29,
      id: 1
    },
    {
      name: "Charlie",
      age: 24,
      id: 2
    },
    {
      name: "Elanor",
      age: 54,
      id: 3
    },
    {
      name: "Michael",
      age: 66,
      id: 4
    }
  ],
  courses = [
    {
      code: "AA01",
      description: "Javascript IIFEs, maps, filters, reduces, etc",
      id: 3
    },
    {
      code: "AO83",
      description: "Arrays, for of loops, etc",
      id: 1
    },
    {
      code: "AX40",
      description: "CSS, HTML",
      id: 3
    },
    {
      code: "BX92",
      description: "SQL, Node",
      id: 2
    },
    {
      code: "CC24",
      description: "PHP, Java",
      id: 1
    },
    {
      code: "DI30",
      description: "MongoDB",
      id: 4
    }
  ],
  theHTML =
    "<table><tr><th>Code</th><th>Description</th><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>",
  container = document.querySelector("#container");

courses.forEach(course =>
  tutors.forEach(
    tutor => tutor.id == course.id && (course["name"] = tutor.name)
  )
);

function filterId(getID) {
  return courses.filter(course => course.id == getID);
}
courses.filterId = filterId;

courses.filterId(3).forEach(function(course) {
  theHTML += "<tr>";
  for (let column in course) {
    theHTML += "<td>" + course[column] + "</td>";
  }
  theHTML += "</tr>";
});

theHTML += "</table>";

container.innerHTML = theHTML;
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a function like that, use Lodash's [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs/#filter):

```
const filtered = _.filter(courses, ["id", 3]);
```

```js
 

let tutors = [
  {
    name: "Bob",
    age: 29,
  id: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Charlie",
    age: 24,
  id: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Elanor",
    age: 54,
  id: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Michael",
    age: 66,
  id: 4
  }
],
courses = [
{
  code: "AA01",
  description: "Javascript IIFEs, maps, filters, reduces, etc",
  id: 3
},
{
  code: "AO83",
  description: "Arrays, for of loops, etc",
  id: 1
},
{
  code: "AX40",
  description: "CSS, HTML",
  id: 3
},
{
  code: "BX92",
  description: "SQL, Node",
  id: 2
},
{
  code: "CC24",
  description: "PHP, Java",
  id: 1
},
{
  code: "DI30",
  description: "MongoDB",
  id: 4
}
  ];

const res = _.filter(courses, ["id", 3]);

console.log(res);
```

```css
 

.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% important; top: auto; }
```

```html
 

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

With `courses.filterId(3)` you are calling a function which is on the Array ( ie. `Array.prototype`) - and it's not there !  When you have defined the function `filterId` it is on the default `window` object.  The simplest fix is to pass both the Array AND the ID to the filterId function, so it will look something like...

`function filterId(arr,ID) { return arr.filter(course => course.id == ID) }`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Before the `Array` prototype is checked, JavaScript will check for a property defined on `courses`. Instead of using a global function or adding this method for all arrays, we can define this helper function directly on `courses`

Answer (score 1):

You try to run function `filterId` as member of courses array, but it doesn't exist in Array prototype.

Option 1 try to use method `find` [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

example

```
let a = [{id:2, test:2}, {id:3, test:3}]
let item = a.find((item) => item.id === 2)
//result {id: 2, test: 2}
```

Option 2 just call `filterId(getID)` it take courses from function scope.